# Selecting rows from two multi-column lists, where values are the same in a chosen column

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

If I have two multi-column lists, for example:

```
ListA = {{1, a1}, {2, a2}, {3, a3}, {4, a4}, {5, a5}, {6, a6}, {7, a7}, {8, a8}}
ListB = {{1, b1}, {3, b3}, {4, b4}, {7, b7}, {8, a8}}
```

I would like to choose the rows from both lists where the elements in a particular column match, in this example column 1 for both lists. I would therefore expect the output:

```
ExpectedList = {{1, a1, b1}, {3, a3, b3}, {4, a4, b4}, {7, a7, b7}, {8, a8, b8}}
```

So far I have looked at `Pick`, `Select` and `Intersection`, but haven't been able to make it work for more than list. An easy (but crude) way to do this would be with a `Table` or loop, but there must be a better way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListA = {{1, a1}, {2, a2}, {3, a3}, {4, a4}, {5, a5}, {6, a6}, {7, a7}, {8, a8}}
ListB = {{1, b1}, {3, b3}, {4, b4}, {7, b7}, {8, a8}}

Flatten[{#, Cases[Join[ListA, ListB], {#, __}][[All, 2]]}] & /@ 
 Intersection[listA[[All, 1]], listB[[All, 1]]]
```

> {{1, a1, b1}, {3, a3, b3}, {4, a4, b4}, {7, a7, b7}, {8, a8, a8}}

Answer (score 6):

```
KeyValueMap[Flatten @* List] @ 
   Select[Length @ # > 1&] @ GroupBy[Join[ListA, ListB], First -> Rest]
```

> ```
> {{1, a1, b1}, {3, a3, b3}, {4, a4, b4}, {7, a7, b7}, {8, a8, a8}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Use `GatherBy` but because it accepts one list, we should join them first:

```
ListA = {{1, a1}, {2, a2}, {3, a3}, {4, a4}, {5, a5}, {6, a6}, {7, a7}, {8, a8}};
ListB = {{1, b1}, {3, b3}, {4, b4}, {7, b7}, {8, a8}};

GatherBy[Join[ListA, ListB], First]

(*Out: {{{1, a1}, {1, b1}}, {{2, a2}}, {{3, a3}, {3, b3}}, {{4, a4}, {4, 
   b4}}, {{5, a5}}, {{6, a6}}, {{7, a7}, {7, b7}}, {{8, a8}, {8, a8}}} *)
```

Now filter those which have a length equal to or less than 1:

```
Cases[GatherBy[Join[ListA, ListB], First], x_List /; Length@x > 1, 1]

(*Out: {{{1, a1}, {1, b1}}, {{3, a3}, {3, b3}}, {{4, a4}, {4, b4}}, {{7, 
   a7}, {7, b7}}, {{8, a8}, {8, a8}}} *)
```

Flatten each case and delete duplicates (for numbers):

```
Cases[GatherBy[Join[ListA, ListB], First], 
 x_List /; Length@x > 1 :> DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[x]], 1]

(*Out: {{1, a1, b1}, {3, a3, b3}, {4, a4, b4}, {7, a7, b7}, {8, a8}} *)
```

`{8, a8}` is because of the last element in `ListB`.

I also suggest: do not start variable names with upper case and not use built-in names in your names too.

Comment: Nice! I'm leaving the question open, only as there is quite a few lines of code in this answer -- in fact doing it with a loop takes less! But if no one else provide a better answer you get the tick as you've answered the question.

Comment: @Q.P. There’s only one line in the code presented, just fyi. Beny builds it up for improved understanding, which is where your impression of multiple lines comes from.

Comment: @CATrevillian My mistake! I clearly didn't read Beny lzd's answer properly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

Using the association route, this turns the lists into associations:

```
ListA = Rule @@@ {{1, a1}, {2, a2}, {3, a3}, {4, a4}, {5, a5}, {6, 
     a6}, {7, a7}, {8, a8}};
ListB = Rule @@@ {{1, b1}, {3, b3}, {4, b4}, {7, b7}, {8, a8}};
ListA //= Association;
ListB //= Association;
```

Now we combine them:

```
intersection = KeyIntersection[{ListA, ListB}];
KeyValueMap[Prepend[First[#2], #1] &, Merge[intersection, List]]
```